# Percona cluster automatic fail-over not working

Tags: centos, percona, mysql-cluster, xtradb, automatic-failover

I'm deploying Percona Xtradb-Cluster and get stuck at automatic fail-over. When I stop node 2 in database not auto update status.
This is log:

2017-06-23 23:37:29 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:37:39 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:37:49 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:37:59 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:38:09 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:38:19 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:38:29 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:38:39 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections
2017-06-23 23:38:49 MySQL_Monitor.cpp:1126:monitor_ping(): [ERROR] Server 192.168.1.11:3306 missed 3 heartbeats, shunning it and killing all the connections

Thanks.

Comment: Please replace the image with a text log.

Comment: I'm edited @AlexanderFedyashov